# Error Value is too great for base in bash

Tags: bash

The below bash script is written for finding the files which are modified with in the last T second where T is supplied from the command line.

```
if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "Wrong number of argument"
    exit 1
fi

for f in *
do
    if [ -x "$f" ]; then
        currenttime=$(date | awk '{print $4}')
        modify=$(date -r "$f" | awk '{print $4}')
        d_c=${currenttime:0:2}
        m_c=${currenttime:3:2}
        s_c=${currenttime:6:2}
        d_m=${modify:0:2}
        m_m=${modify:3:2}
        s_m=${modify:6:2}
        let "1d_c *= 24"
        let "m_c *= 60"
        let "second_c = d_c+m_c+s_c"
            let "d_m *= 24"
        let "m_m *= 60"
        let "second_m=d_m+m_m+s_m"
        let "diff=second_c-second_m"
        if [ $diff -lt $1 ]; then
            echo $f
        fi
    fi
do
```

ne

But I am getting the below error in that.

```
./recent.sh: line 46: let: 09: value too great for base (error token is "09")
./recent.sh: line 47: let: 09: value too great for base (error token is "09")
./recent.sh: line 49: let: 09: value too great for base (error token is "09")
```

I know that this error is coming due to the large value in the variable and I have to make the variable decimal but I don't know how to do it in my case(inside the let command, how to make them decimal).

Comment: You have some stray double-quotes in `let "1d_c *= "24"` and `let "m_c *= "60"`, which completely break your Bash syntax. Please confirm that the code you have posted here is correct, and produces the errors you claim. (Hint: it doesn't. Your error-messages refer to lines 46, 47, and 49, but you've only posted 28 lines of code. Please fix.)

Comment: `let "1d_c *= "24"`? you're missing a `"` char, but I don't believe you need any `"` chars. Also read up about arithmetic processing available in bash, i.e. `(( m_m *= 60 )); echo "$m_m`.

Comment: Also the error you're getting is when bash thinks it is operating on Octal values, i.e. 00-08, so 09, is out of range. Good luck.

Comment: Could you please tell me the solution.... how to fix this problem

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `09`, due to the leading `0`, is interpreted as octal, whereas (as you've surmised) you need it to be interpreted as decimal.

To fix this, you need to bypass `let`'s normal convert-variable-to-number process. Instead of writing, for example, this:

```
let "second_c = d_c+m_c+s_c"
```

you should write this:

```
let "second_c = 10#$d_c + 10#$m_c + 10#$s_c"
```

By prepending `$`, you're asking Bash to substitute in the variable-value *as a string* — so, for example, if `d_c` is `09`, then `10#$d_c` will be `10#09`. The `10#` prefix tells `let` that the number should be interpreted as base-10.

---

Actually, on second thought, it's probably best to do this when you initially populate these variables; for example:

```
d_c=$(( 10#${currenttime:0:2} ))
```

That way you don't have to do it everywhere that you use them. (And also, it puts any errors closer to their source, which makes debugging easier.)